# Automatically load obj to Maya

Tags: batch-processing, maya

I would like to batch render 1000 models using Maya. I have set up a Maya scene and I need to render these models one-by-one with the same scene

I am thinking of writing a MEL script that does the following thing:
(1) Load a model obj
(2) Render it
(3) Replace the current obj by the next obj, render it and repeat

Can someone give me some hint how to do it? I am not familiar with MEL. Thanks!

Comment: Hi mushin, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: These objects are all in one folder?

Comment: Hi @kartikg3, yes they are.

Comment: Are the point numbers the same? So is the the same mesh differently deformed if so you can load it as a blend shape.

Comment: Hi @joojaa, no unfortunately. The meshes have different number of vertices as well as mesh topology

Comment: Ok, the just loop over the files. Longer explanation below. Oh and this post is better suited for stack overflow than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this. What you do is you turn echo on and open the script editor then do this once and copy the instructions to the code line below and replace with variables.

Anyway a simple example (caveat emptor, I wouldn't use this for several reasons well beyond the scope of this post might work fine for you):

```
$folder = "P:/ath/to/data/";
$files = `getFileList -filespec "*.obj" 
                      -folder $folder`;

for ($filename in $files){
    file -import -type "OBJ" -ra true 
         -namespace "IMP" -options "mo=1"  
         -pr -loadReferenceDepth "all" 
         ($folder+$filename);
    setAttr "defaultRenderGlobals.imageFilePrefix"
            -type "string" $filename;
    RenderIntoNewWindow;
    delete "IMP:*";
    namespace -rm IMP;

    print ($filename+" processing. \n");
}
```

Images should now be in */images/tmp*  folder. There are several things you could do better or nicer but this is just a very quick example. **EDIT:** The code can get confused, in multi view layouts if the focus is not set properly it would be better to explicitly name renderable cameras.

For example instead you could just run this form your OS's command line with render command and a script loop. This has some benefits for real sustained production.

Comment: Of course it does, I have at least 15 years of experience with Maya, feel free also to up vote if you find the post useful. Anyway be careful demons lie this way.

Comment: Excellent answer Joojaa. Adding the namespace each time for safety is a great touch.

Comment: @kartikg3 its mainly because it makes deleting all the stuff imported easier for me safety is just a side effect.

Comment: @joojaa I will certainly up vote when I have enough reputation

Comment: @mushin Sure, NP just making sure you understand the metagame that is played on this site. 7 points to go.